# angular routing isn't working on browser refresh

Tags: angular

in my app.routing.ts file I have:

```
....{path:'', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}.....
```

when I first run the app, it correctly loads my home page and I have a url of http://localhost:50001/home

If I press the refresh button on the browser, the url doesn't change, but I get a blank page.

If I change one of the above routing paths to be:

```
 {path:'', component: HomeComponent }
```

in Both instances, i.e. initial load and browser refresh, I get the home page but the url becomes http://localhost:50001 How do I get it to keep the /home part on the url

as per @pc_coder request :

```
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './message/message.component';
import { MaintainDataExportComponent } from './data-export/maintain-data-export.component';
import { DefineDataRetentionComponent } from './define-data-retention/define-data-retention.component';
import { MaintainAgentsComponent } from './agents/maintain-agents.component';
import { MaintainSuppliersComponent } from './agents/maintain-suppliers.component';
import { MaintainDtnAutomationComponent } from './dtn-automation/maintain-dtn-automation.component';
import { MaintainSscsComponent } from './sscs/maintain-sscs.component';
import { DeleteHalfHourlyDataComponent } from './delete-half-hourly-data/delete-half-hourly-data.component';
import { DeleteInvalidAppointmentsComponent } from './delete-invalid-appointments/delete-invalid-appointments.component';
import { MaintainSccLoadControlComponent } from './ssc-load-control/maintain-ssc-load-control.component';

import { MaintainDataExportResolver } from '../services/resolvers/maintain-data-export.resolver';
import { MessageResolver } from '../services/resolvers/message.resolver';
import { MaintainAgentsResolver } from '../services/resolvers/maintain-agents.resolver';
import { DataRetentionResolver } from '../services/resolvers/data-retention.resolver';
import { BusinessScenariosResolver } from '../services/resolvers/dtn-automation.resolver';
import { SscValuesResolver } from '../services/resolvers/ssc-values.resolver';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

  {
    path: 'message',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':pipelineId',
        component: MessageComponent,
        resolve: {
          message: MessageResolver,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'maintain-agents',
    component: MaintainAgentsComponent,
    resolve: {
      agents: MaintainAgentsResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'maintain-suppliers',
    component: MaintainSuppliersComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'maintain-data-export',
    component: MaintainDataExportComponent,
    resolve: {
      exportTypes: MaintainDataExportResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'maintain-dtn-automation',
    component: MaintainDtnAutomationComponent,
    resolve: {
      scenarios: BusinessScenariosResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'maintain-ssc',
    component: MaintainSscsComponent,
    resolve: {
      sscs: SscValuesResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'delete-half-hourly-data',
    component: DeleteHalfHourlyDataComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'delete-invalid-appointments',
    component: DeleteInvalidAppointmentsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'define-data-retention',
    component: DefineDataRetentionComponent,
    resolve: {
      retentionTypes: DataRetentionResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'maintain-ssc-load-control',
    component: MaintainSccLoadControlComponent,
    resolve: {
      sscs: SscValuesResolver,
    },
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },

];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
});
```

Comment: When you declare routes, the default route should be at the end of the file, the order of declaration is important. Could you try to move the default route at the end ?

Comment: @thib_o_o Placing the empty path above my last entry of  `{path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }` gives the same outcome.

Comment: @pc_coder still the same, I get the `/home` back on my url line but a blank page

Comment: Can you share your routing module in questio please ?

Comment: @pc_coder I have added the full file in the question. The routing works for all routes and browser refresh works for all other routes as well. It's just the refresh on the 'home' route

Comment: from the official documentation, https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects the two last routes are the default route and the fallback route. Don't have other idea on your problem...